# Explicit generators for homotopy groups of Lie groups

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, homotopy-theory

I would like to know explicit formulas for generators of the infinite cyclic summands in the homotopy groups of Lie groups, in the form of continuous (or smooth if possible) maps $S^n\to G$.

It is fairly easy to find explicit matrix formulas for those generators in case $U(n)$ or $SU(n)$, e.g. [in this paper.](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0301192) It is still possible to find more or less explicit descriptions for all the other classical groups, e.g. A. Lundell, Y. Tosa: Explicit construction of nontrivial elements of homotopy groups of classical Lie groups, J. Math. Phys. 31 (1990), 1494-1502.

So I was wondering if formulas for generators of homotopy groups of Lie groups exist in general. Moreover, I would prefer not having a case-by-case distinction, but some description that is uniform across all types (after all, the degrees in which infinite cyclic summands appear in the homotopy of Lie groups is determined by the root system). Has such a thing been done in the literature, and if so, where?

Even if no general such explicit formulas are available, I would be interested in knowing what general method (working uniformly for all types) could be used to produce such explicit maps $S^n\to G$. I was thinking about using Bott's generating varieties, but I am not sure exactly how to proceed...

To add some motivation: eventually, I will have a left-invariant differential $n$-form $\omega$ on $G$ and I want to evaluate $\int_{S^n}p^\ast \omega$ for $p:S^n\to G$ with $p$ a generator as above. For this, only tangent information is relevant, but I do not know how I would get the tangent information without actually producing the whole map.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the book "Topology of Lie groups I and II'' by Mimura and Toda?

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu: yes, I looked at it. Of course, it contains a lot of computations of cohomology and homotopy of Lie groups, but I did not find any explicit maps $S^n\to G$ generating homotopy groups - most of the computations are done using long exact sequences and spectral sequences. I might well have missed the relevant statements - did you have any specific part of the book in mind where explicit maps $S^n\to G$ could be found?

Comment: If you did not find it in that book I'm out of good suggestions.

Comment: You know that for pi_3 it comes from the inclusion of an SU(2) subgroup? This can be done on the level of Lie algebras quite explicitly... The 11-sphere (and 9-sphere in the case of SU(n)) seem a whole lot more difficult.